# symfony2. Cannot load pdo drivers

Tags: php, symfony, windows-7, pdo, x86

When i'm try to create db with

```
doctrine:database:create
```

There are errors(mysql or postgresql):

```
Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
could not find driver
```

my parametrs.yml:

```
parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 3306
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: 1dffcb10ddfc2bbc4f211d773f2524557
database_path: null
```

When i'm trying to map my classes to db

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Demos/BlogBundle/Entity/Post
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

there are error:

```
[PDOException]         
  could not find drive
```

lines uncomment in the file php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

print_r(get_loaded_extensions()) result :

Array (... mbstring [35] => exif [36] => gd [37] => gettext [38] => mysql [39] => Phar [40] => pdo_mysql [41] => pdo_pgsql [42] => pgsql ... )

i found http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php
user gerrywastaken wrote, that there maybe need commands:

--with-pdo-mysql[=DIR]    PDO: MySQL support. DIR is the MySQL base directoy
                                 If mysqlnd is passed as DIR, the MySQL native
                                 native driver will be used [/usr/local]

i can't understand where execute this commands, or configure...

Comment: That command at the bottom is the php compilation command. If this is an initial LAMP server setup. If not, try this site's guides. http://www.tecmint.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-redhat-centos-fedora/

Comment: This solved same problem for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart your web server after uncommenting these lines in php.ini configuration