# why enabling pdo drivers did not works in php.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, exception, model-view-controller

I have a problem saying pdo exception.  could not find driver I tried un- commenting and adding drivers/libraries in php.ini file. Still the error is same. below are a few lines of my php.ini file. 
I even tried installing pdo drivers with the following command. 
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql then i got another list of errors. the error is also posted below. Seriously out of clue. Please help me here

I have my laravel5 on port 8000 (i run the app by localhost:8000)
and phpmyadmin is operated on localhost:8080

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

```
usman@usman-cs:~/lampstack-5.5.26-0/php$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
[sudo] password for usman: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.13 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image: error description]

Comment: php5-mysql is not going to install pdo drivers, call sudo apt-get install pdo-mysql

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server

Comment: running that commands says "unable to locate package pdo mysql"

Comment: Run apt-cache search pdo to find any package that contains pdo in it?