# PHP SQL with autocomplete string searching for first name LIKE input value OR last name LIKE input value AND another query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm basically trying to accomplish this query with autocomplete (each keystroke triggers a query)(it's working, except last name isn't querying correctly):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM names WHERE (first like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%') OR (last like '%" . $_POST["keyword"] . "') AND year>$curr_year";
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You're missing an additional level of () around the OR conditions.  `$query="SELECT * FROM names WHERE ((first like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%') OR (Last like '" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%')) AND year>$curr_year";`  What you have is looking for first name like wihtout a year and last name like with a specific year.

Comment: Well, what would be the correct way to query `last`? You're matching on the _end_ of lastname.

Comment: You should use prepared statements.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! My updated query is: $query="SELECT * FROM names WHERE ((first like '%" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%') OR (last like '%" . $_POST["keyword"] . "%')) AND gradyear>$curr_year";

Comment: Also, I'll look into prepared statements ... what are some of the advantages?

Comment: @faalbane Well, the first person called O'Connor won't crash your search for a start :)

Comment: Thank you for this advice ... I'm researching right now; I see the advantages ... Wow ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM names WHERE ((first like :first) OR (last like :last)) AND gradyear > :year";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$con = $pdo->prepare($query);
$con->execute([
 ':last'=> "%$_POST[keyword]",
 ':first'=> "$_POST[keyword]%",
 ':year'=>$curr_year
]);
$results = $con->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That is how you do a prepared statement. The reason why you would want to use it is to prevent a [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) for prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you! I'm researching PDO and SQL injection right now ... Wow ... I appreciate the advice ...

Comment: Is "%$_POST[keyword]%" and $_POST["keyword"] equivalent?

Comment: No, you have to add the `%` wildcards around the variable. `"%".$_POST["keyword"]."%"` is the equivalent, but it has more characters in it. The wildcards tell the database to look for anything that contains the keyword. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: Thank you ... do you know how to install PDO - MySql driver on server? I have access to web root and PHPMyAdmin ...

Comment: pdo and mysqli are standard libraries in php5 apt get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server

Comment: You need to bind each placeholder, also looks like OP only wants any trailing characters on first, and any leading characters on last.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\filename.php:21 Stack trace: #0

Comment: What would be the mysqli syntax?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php If you are using windows, then install using that. And here is the mysqli syntax http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php