# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() when connecting to the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I get an error when trying to connect to my database with mysqli on PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  mysqli_connect()     in /home/mywebsite/public_html/connection.php:7

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBname);
```

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424982/how-to-enable-mysqli-extension-in-php-7

Answer (score 3):

1. First check, if mysqli is enabled: `phpinfo()`
2. The mysqli PHP extension is not installed on your server. Contact to your server administrator.

OR

3. If you host the server yourself, in the **php.ini** file remove the semicolon in front of the extension **extension=php_mysqli.dll**.

Hope, this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using PHP PDO for database connection. Its got better performance and I think the code looks better.

But to speak on your error, it looks like php doesnt have a reference to mysqli library. Did you explicitly install the php-mysql package? Its also possible that the environment variable path is not pointing to the right location on the filesystem.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PDO' not found, (i think im just gonna switch host)

Comment: Well, you gotta install the PDO class.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server

Answer (score 0):

Your php not instaled mysql connector ,
for install linux :

sudo install php-mysqli

Happens when php extensions are not being used by default.
 In your php.ini file, change

;extension=php_mysql.dll
to
extension=php_mysql.dll.

Comment: what is this command, install? to what package it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli PHP extension` is not installed on your new server.

Contact to your server administrator.

If you host the server yourself, in the ***`php.ini`*** file remove the semicolon in front of the extension **`extension=php_mysqli.dll`**