# Change PDO driver

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make my own website with MySQL database. Making it using MAMP was a great succes for me, so I bought Raspberry Pi (Raspbian on board) to make a server from it (and learn ofc). Apache2 is working, php5 also, MariaDB is installed and seems to be working (I can use statements in terminal), but phpinfo() says, that there is no PDO driver. When I install SQLite, it becomes driver with no issue at all (but I want to use MySQL).

So my question is: How to force php (apache?) to make MySQL his PDO driver?

Googling and looking for solutions for days is killing me.

EDIT:`sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` has `Depends: libmysqlclient18 but it is not installable` issue. Also I have multiple php.ini files in /etc/php5 (more folders here with php.ini files). Which is the "chosen one"?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PDO driver on MySQL Linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server)

Comment: Trying yesterday. I have 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 but it is not installable' issue. Not found solution for that

Comment: make a php file with content: `<?php phpinfo();`
then open that in browser, it will show all configurations - and where the config file is.

Comment: Seen that, done that. Nothing changed