# Unable to connect to DB on Azure Ubuntu machine with PHP 8.0

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, pdo

I'm trying to connect my Wordpress 6.1.1 installation installed on an Azure VM (Ubuntu) to my DB, also installed on Azure. I ran the "php -m" command to get the list of available PHP extensions on the server and I got this list:

Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zlib

I'm trying to use PDO (which is listed and therefore available) to connect with the following code in wp-config.php

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'nome_database' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'nome_utente' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'host' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

$pdo = new PDO( "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 
array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING ) );
```

but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /home/site/wwwroot/wp- 
config.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-config.php(57): PDO- 
>__construct('mysql:host=MYHOST...', 'USERNAME...', '***********', Array) #1 
/home/site/wwwroot/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/site/wwwr...') #2 
/home/site/wwwroot/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/site/wwwr...') #3 
/home/site/wwwroot/index.php(17): require('/home/site/wwwr...') #4 {main} thrown in 
/home/site/wwwroot/wp-config.php on line 57
```

Can you help me understand what's going on? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please write the whole question in English, not just parts of it.

Comment: I also tried with a Mysqli string:

    $con=mysqli_init(); 
    mysqli_ssl_set($con, NULL, NULL, 
    "/home/site/wwwroot/ssl/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem", NULL, NULL); 
    mysqli_real_connect($con, "mysql.mysql.database.azure.com", 
    "myuser@mysql", "mypassword", "mydbname", 
    3306);
but i receive this: 
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /home/site/wwwroot/wp-config.php:57 Stack trace: #0 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-load.php(50): require_once() #1 /home/site/wwwroot/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/site/wwwr...')

Answer (score 0):

> ````bash
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-  config.php:57 Stack trace: #0
> /home/site/wwwroot/wp-config.php(57): PDO- ```
> ````

This error code occurs when the PHP-MYSQL extension is not properly installed in your local VM, Even when PDO extension-

> mysqlnd openssl pcre PDO pdo_sqlite

is installed in your VM you need to additionally install the PHP-MYSQL driver in the VM for the PDO extension to function properly

You can try installing the php-mysql package with the below commands:-

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

[image]

```bash
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can run these commands to install all 3 packages together:-

```bash
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql -y
```

OR

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apache2 \
                 ghostscript \
                 libapache2-mod-php \
                 mysql-server \
                 php \
                 php-bcmath \
                 php-curl \
                 php-imagick \
                 php-intl \
                 php-json \
                 php-mbstring \
                 php-mysql \
                 php-xml \
                 php-zip
```

[image]

```bash
php -m
```

[image]

Restart your WordPress server and try the DB connection again.

```bash
sudo service apache2 restart
```

[image]

You can also explicitly navigate to the php-extension file and validate its status too. Make sure to check the status of the server on which your WordPress is running and restart that server.

Extension commands:-

```ini
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

**References:-**

[Install and configure WordPress | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#2-install-dependencies)

[php - Installing PDO driver on MySQL Linux server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375061/installing-pdo-driver-on-mysql-linux-server) By Jani Hartikainen artagis, Avinash Tiwari,

[PHP: MySQL (PDO) - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)